# Error binding make_unique

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr, stdbind

I'm having trouble using `std::bind` with `std::make_unique`.

I have an object to whose constructor I pass factory functions for making `std::unique_ptr`s of objects of another class type.

Using VS2013, this works:

```
Tester tester( 
    [](){return std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE>( 0,7 ); },
    [](){return std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThread>( 0,7 ); },
    20 );
```

This gives me compile errors:

```
Tester tester( 
    std::bind( std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE>,0,7 ),
    std::bind( std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThread>,0,7 ),
    20 );
```

The error messages state:

> error C2512: 'AlphaBetaSingleThread' : no appropriate default
>   constructor available
>
> error C2512: 'AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE' : no
>   appropriate default constructor available

Why does the `std::bind` approach fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_unique` is defined as follows:

§ 20.8.1.4 [unique.ptr.create]

> ```
> template <class T, class... Args> unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> <sup>1</sup> *Remarks*: This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless `T` is not an array.
>
> <sup>2</sup> *Returns*: `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)).`

By explicitly instantiating this function template with `std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE>` you end up with the following specialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE> make_unique()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE>(new AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE());
}
```

That is, it won't anymore let you pass additional arguments that would be forwarded to the constructor of `AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE`, and instead, will try to use a default constructor of `AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE` (which doesn't exist as the error message states).

You can work around that by specifying also type template parameter `Args`:

```
std::make_unique<AlphaBetaSingleThreadSSE, const int&, const int&>
```

but then you won't benefit from perfect-forwarding and this is not a portable solultion anyway. A better solution is to stay with a lambda.

Comment: "A better solution is to stay with a lambda." -- actually, the answer to 90%+ of `std::bind` questions.